# Office365 30 emails per minute limite problem .Net

Tags: c#, .net, email, office365, limit

I recently end up having a problem with the limite of 30 mails per minute from office 365, I'm making this question to look for other solutions and also show the solution I did to overcome the 30 mails per minute limit.

Answer (score 1):

for the 30 mails per minute problem you can solve it just by creatring a Queued background service: [enter link description here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio#queued-background-tasks)

Then you can just create a class EmailQueuedHostedService that inherits from QueuedHostedService and override the BackgroundProcessing method like this:

```
public class EmailQueuedHostedService : QueuedHostedService
{
    private readonly ILogger<EmailQueuedHostedService> _logger;
    private readonly TimersTimer _timer;
    private int MailsSent = 0;
    private const int MailsSentInMinute = 30;

    public EmailQueuedHostedService(IBackgroundTaskQueue taskQueue,
        ILogger<EmailQueuedHostedService> logger) : base(taskQueue, logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _timer = new TimersTimer(60 * 1000);
        _timer.Elapsed += (sender, e) => MailsSent = 0;
        _timer.Start();
    }

    protected override async Task BackgroundProcessing(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            if (MailsSent < MailsSentInMinute)
            {
                var workItem = await TaskQueue
                    .DequeueAsync(stoppingToken);

                try
                {
                    await workItem(stoppingToken);

                    MailsSent++;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    _logger.LogError(ex,
                        "Error occurred executing {WorkItem}.", nameof(workItem));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now your Email Queue service will control the number of emails send per minute so they don't throw an exception if you pass the limit.